# JNA:com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception- access denied

Tags: java, windows, winapi, jna

I  use following code to control a windows  service from java program

```
public class PostgresService2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
            {
                W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();
                serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SERVICE_STOP);
                W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("DBService",
                        Winsvc.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP);
                service.stopService();
                service.close();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
    }
}
```

This gives error on windows7 (64bit) machine

```
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Access is denied.
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service.queryStatus(W32Service.java
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service.waitForNonPendingState(W32S
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service.stopService(W32Service.java
        at chs.capitalmigrate.ui.PostgresService2.main(PostgresService2.java
```

The shell from where the command is run has administrative privileges.  How I can provide full access?

Answer (score 1):

I am using SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS and that works. Not sure if that helps.

```
 W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager();
               serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
               W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("servicename", Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
```