# Exception in thread While using Win32 services

Tags: java, jna, win32-process

I am using Following Piece of Code to Regulate Services in Remote machine:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32Service;
 import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32ServiceManager;
 import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winsvc;

 public class CopyOfserviceRestart {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

//public void services()
{


W32ServiceManager serviceManager = new W32ServiceManager("TPATADTS5", null);   
serviceManager.open(Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  
W32Service service = serviceManager.openService("Exponent Manager Service",   Winsvc.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  
 if( service.queryStatus().dwCurrentState == Winsvc.SERVICE_RUNNING)
 {
   System.out.println("Chalche");
}
else
{
   service.startService(); 
   service.close();
   System.out.println("Done");
 }  

 }
  }}
```

Everything Is fine for Few server However For Other few serevr I am Getting Following Error:

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Access is denied.
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32ServiceManager.open(W32ServiceManager.java:47)
    at com.accenture.service.CopyOfserviceRestart.main(CopyOfserviceRestart.java:15)

Comment: Is this an applet or an application?  I'm not entirely sure, but I do think you need to set up the Security Policy for Java to work with the native services manager. Also, it has to run in a run level that's high enough to perform the actions required, like restart etc.

Comment: check related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120815/jnacom-sun-jna-platform-win32-win32exception-access-denied

Comment: @Ewald This is ansimple Java programme no complication in that part but, access is getting denied for ceratin server, si there any windows key that we have to register or something which might help the Java call to access Windowws services?

Comment: Ah, have you tried Sachin Bhansali's suggested resource? I'm curious to know...

Comment: @ewald Used the same thing that Bhansali Suggested, Infact I used the code from solution itself but same error

Comment: Can you do the same thing without using Java? In other words, can you do it as the user you are? The Java runtime will operate under your username and password in Windows, and if you do not have sufficient rights to perform the operation, it will still fail, no matter what you do, until you get the rights.

Comment: Yes, i have sufficient credentials to Login into the server and check the service, infact I have Admin Credentials